# Access values of environment variables from an object in Node

Tags: node.js, express, security, environment-variables

In Node framework eg: Express, there is a .env file and that's where the environment variables are stored. Is it safe for me to have an object in code and the reason to do so is to eliminate the need to type in `process.env` whenever I need it, I could just do EnvVars.NODE_ENV and with intellisense suggestion too. For example,

.env file

```
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=3000
```

env-vars.ts

```
export const EnvVars = {
  NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  PORT: process.env.PORT
}
```

Is it safe in terms of coding/app security's perspective? Any possibilities that someone could obtain these values from the frontend that is connected to this server code through any methods?